# alt-tab for IR remote

Tags: unity, remote, application-switcher

Is there a way to set up a key combination that brings up the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> interface and leaves it up after releasing the keys, allowing to navigate between open windows with arrow keys and selecting them with the enter key?

I have a media pc set up with Kodi and steam, I would like to be able to **alt-tab** via a remote control so, I do not need a keyboard plugged in, but the normal <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> interface requires you to keep holding down alt to keep it up. this does not work with an IR remote.

I am able to bind any key combination I want to the IR remote using a FLIRC which is a USB IR receiver that emulates an HID device.

Comment: Honestly i don't use remote before but i have  a wireless mouse i only use edges to switch between application like ubuntu gnome 1) this screen shot top left corner http://i.imgur.com/UU3tfVM.png
2) bottom left corner http://i.imgur.com/l3hhs6x.png
3)bottom right corner http://i.imgur.com/9lTdJah.png 

if that what you asking for i can post an answer to add

Comment: Maybe Super-S or Super-W (to zoom out and display all windows)? I haven't used Unity in a while, but it's worth a try. The Super key is usually the "Windows" key,  I think

Comment: @MohamedSlama i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @NickWeinberg that allows me to look at the zoomed out desktop but i am unable to switch between open windows/applications.

Comment: i mention their's another way for switching between application if it suitable  here's a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhmEUqzfxX0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @MohamedSlama i am unable to watch youtube videos but i think the way you are suggesting uses the mouse which is not an option. I;m essentially using a TV remote to control the PC as well as an xbox 360 controller when i play games. i do not have the mouse courser mapped and would prefer not to.

Comment: you can assign with one key if you would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install ***Compiz*** using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins-extra
```

After installing compiz open dash and type ccsm.

1. Open **compiz**.
2. In **compiz window management** enable **shift Switcher**.
3. Assign **initiate key (All Workspaces)**.
4. grab any key you want.

[image]

Comment: i have installed compiz and compiz-plugins-extra but when i open dash and type in ccsm nothing comes up.

Comment: restart or logout

Comment: or write ccsm on terminal

Comment: have tried both, i restarted and then tried via dash and terminal

Comment: when you type ccsm on terminal what happen or what's the error message

Comment: ok, had to install compizconfig-settings-manager (or something like that anyway) installed it and opened ccsm, found the setting in your screenshot and set it to F3 (a key i already had bound to the remote that i was not using)  but it does not seem to have any effect. i even tried a restart.

Comment: is it working in your pc  using keyboard ??

Comment: no. nothing at all happens when i hit F3.

Comment: ok try another key may F3 assigned by any application or ubuntu temporary try F4

Comment: nope, that does not work either, also tried super+F4

Comment: plz can you screen shot your compiz window like my screen shot??

Comment: [here](https://flashplace.net/owncloud/index.php/s/9KZbFba5rHbNc90)

Comment: you not enable it plz tick the check box  to enable

Comment: check box under **Use this plugin**.

Comment: ok great, thanks. am doing all this from the other side of the room so its hard to read whats on screen. it works perfect.